# Automatically delete junction data along with DELETE of a record?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, junction-table

I have users, have offers, and a junction table users_offers.

Is there a setup I can carry out with foreign key relations that can ensure that junction data will be automatically deleted when I delete any users or offers?

Comment: cascade delete in a trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a referential action: ON DELETE CASCADE, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id int PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE offer (
    offer_id int PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE user_offer (
    user_id int,
    offer_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, offer_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES offer (offer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18f68/2)

Interestingly enough, it seems that specifying referential action in "shorthand" foreign key syntax doesn't work (confirmed under MySQL 5.5.30, 5.6.6 m9). The following gets parsed, but when `user` is deleted, the corresponding `user_offer` doesn't get deleted:

```
CREATE TABLE user_offer (
    user_id int REFERENCES user (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    offer_id int REFERENCES offer (offer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, offer_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify this within your model creation:

```
CREATE TABLE users_offers (user_id INT NOT NULL,
                           offer_id INT NOT NULL,
                           PRIMARY KEY (user_id, offer_id),
                           FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
                               ON DELETE CASCADE,
                           FOREIGN KEY (offer_id) REFERENCES offers(id)
                               ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

You can see a working example in [this Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d28b/2).